# Query return hyperlinks in text fields in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

How to return data table`s text fields as hyperlinks to open the detailed view thereafter: all fields of the search item in Microsoft Access 2010? Similar to ASP.NET GridView with column hyperlinks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand, you are having a datasheet and would like to click on each ID to open the full details.

idea:

1. make a field act as a hyperlink
2. build a new form to show the full details
3. use the onClick event to open a new window with your full details

To achieve this:

you need to create a new form where your full details will be showed. I guess you know this already. in case:

1. select the table/query you are trying to use as datasource for the
   Form.
2. goto menu > create > Form ( this will create a default form with all fields in your table/query)
3. Save the from "frm_view_in_full"
4. Goto the main DataSheet/gridview from where you would like to call this form
5. select the field you would like to make it hyperlink and goto the field's properties.
6. set the fields property "is Hyperlink = Yes"
7. goto the on event property for the selected field

now you can simply call the form with where condition like:

```
docmd.OpenForm "frm_view_in_full", acNormal,,"[whereConditionField]=" & Condition
```